# Theorems not Formulable in Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, foundations

Several sites I have been reading say that set theory is a good foundation for mathematics because virtually every theorem can be cast into a theorem in set theory.

What is an example of a theorem that can't be cast in terms of set theory? Is there any reason we know of so far to doubt set theory's ability to describe all of mathematics?

Comment: As long as mathematics is formulated in logical means, and the objects of interest can be seen as sets, set theory can internalize everything.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So then why do sites feel the need to say virtually every theorem, as opposed to every theorem? What objects of interests can't be seen as sets?

Comment: Because history taught us to be cautious, and there is always need for wiggle room. Do meta-theoretic theorems count or not? Can classes be formalized or not? It depends on the context, and how you wish to interpret things. So being a bit vague is good.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can't classes be formalized?

Comment: Well. It's complicated. They can to some basic extent in ZF, or much better in the conservative extension of NBG, or you might want to consider classes as definable collections of a fixed set model in 's larger universe, which is just fine but requires you to assume the existence of said model as a new axiom. All these are set theoretic solutions to how to formalize classes, but they are all very different from how you formalize measure theory, or linear algebra.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. But so it's still possible there might be a way to define classes in ZF without these assuming these axioms? Or is it provable that you can't? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Again, to a certain degree we can formalize classes. But only for a very limited degree. Depending on what you want to say or do, ZF might not suffice. Then you have to step out to the meta-theory (like stepping from field theory to ZF when defining what is an order complete field).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand that we can to a certain degree, but what's stopping us from doing it any further? I just mean to say that just because we haven't been able to find a way, doesn't mean such a way doesn't exist, right?

Comment: According to what I read [at physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/path-integral-vs-measure-on-infinite-dimensional-space/1897#1897): "Currently, there is no satisfying mathematical formalization of the [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation)." Personally, I do ont know about this area. But maybe someone else can tell you more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a precise sense in which any foundation of math will fail to formalize certain statements which we should believe are true.

Suppose I view the mathematical universe as a structure $V$ in the language of set theory (this is the point of view taken by ZF, ZFC, NF, etc.). Then - informally - I can talk about the theory of $V$ in this language. This theory can be coded by a single real, and - assuming $V$ really is "everything" - this real should exist. So

> There is a real coding the true $\{\in\}$-theory of the universe

is a "true" statement. However, this sentence cannot be expressed in the language of set theory in any satisfactory way, by Tarski's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem. We could expand our language to make this sentence expressible, but then truth in that expanded language would not be expressible, so we would need to further expand the language . . .

Exactly how problematic you find this sort of thing varies from person to person; but certainly I find it a good argument for caution - I wouldn't want to commit myself to *never* using a more expressive language, even if I don't think I'm likely to need it.

---

Note that this has nothing to do with classes (although there is some overlap), and is really an essential feature of how first-order logic works.

Comment: Just because you can't code the truth doesn't mean it's not out there! If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then $V_\kappa$ knows its own truth, it just doesn't know it is its own truth. The truth is out there. And I'm not just saying that to celebrate the short return of Mulder and Scully to our screens.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is true, but since the question was about *expressibility* in the language of set theory, I still think this answer is reasonably appropriate. I didn't mean to imply that the real coding truth can't exist, just that we can't satisfyingly express "the real coding truth exists" in the language of the universe. (And +1 for sf!)

Comment: This language is fairly foreign to me, and I'm trying to parse it- what do you mean a real? Like a real number?

Comment: @Bob Yes, a real number - which we can view as just a sequence of 0s and 1s (via binary expansion). List the sentences in the language of set theory (or any fixed language of your choice) in some reasonable way (e.g. lexicographically) as $\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ...$; then a real $r$ codes truth if the $n$th binary bit of $r$ is 1 iff $\varphi_n$ is true. This definition, and the statement "a real coding truth exists", are made outside the language of set theory - and my point is they can't be made inside it in a "reasonable" way.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help!